# Difficulty adjusting text box position

Tags: html, angularjs

**This is my HTML code:**

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Welcome to ShopialMedia</h1>
</div>
<h2> Sign up if you haven't already </h2>
<div ng-controller = "signupController">
  <h3> Email : </h3> 
  <input type = "text" placeholder="Enter your Email" ng-model = "userEmail" id ="textEmail"  ></input>
<h4> Password: </h4>
<input type = "text" placeholder="Enter your password" ng-model = "userPass"  id = "textPass"></input>
<h5> First Name: </h5>
<input type = "text" placeholder="Enter your First Name" ng-model = "userFName" id = textFname ></input>
<h6> Last Name : </h6>
<input type = "text" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" ng-model = "userLName" id = textLname ></input>
<h7> Age : </h7>
<input type = "text" placeholder="Enter your Age" ng-model = "userAge" id = textAge ></input>
<button type = "submit" ng-click="signup()"> Sign Up </button>
</div>
```

**The actual output:**

[image]

I want the text boxes to be beside its corresponding header.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use display:inline-block; like so

```
input{
  display:inline-block;
}
h3,h4,h5,h6,h7{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CZorio13/6fs7Ly23/) for result...

You could also use bootstrap do this very quickly and make it look nice.

EDIT: You should use labels like the other answer suggests, I just assumed you had put heading elements there for a reason based on the fact you're using one of each type.

Answer (score 0):

try using labels instead of headers like this:

**HTML:**

```
<label> Email : </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email" ng-model="userEmail" id="textEmail"></input>
<BR>
<label> Password: </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your password" ng-model="userPass" id="textPass"></input>
<BR>
<label> First Name: </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your First Name" ng-model="userFName" id=t extFname></input>
<BR>
<label> Last Name : </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" ng-model="userLName" id=t extLname></input>
<BR>
<label> Age : </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Age" ng-model="userAge" id=t extAge></input>
<BR>
<button type="submit" ng-click="signup()"> Sign Up </button>
```

**CSS for outlining:**

```
input {
  width: 200px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 125px;
}
```

[Fiddle can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/wcbd55e5/)